# how to set custom destination properly in drupal url

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to place the destination in a drupal path like this:

```
http://myhost/root-folder/node/100/delete?destination=node/150?nid=300
```

It's a little bit unusual in terms of drupal terminology, but this is my requirement.

When I visit the above url it's shows me a delete button and a cancel link. But when I click on the cancel link, the redirected page url becomes like this:

```
http://myhost/root-folder/node/150%3Fnid%3D300
```

instead of

```
http://myhost/root-folder/node/150?nid=300
```

i.e. `myhost` = `localhost`

This means it's replacing the `?` with code `%3F` and `=` with `%3D`.

How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: What do you mean 'trying to replace the destination'? how? where? when?

Comment: it's not replace. it's place@clive

Comment: My mistake, see the answer below :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually totally correct, the second `?` is after the query string identifier (i.e. the first `?`), so it *has* to be url encoded to remain valid.

Don't worry about it though, when Drupal performs it's redirects by using the [`drupal_get_destination()` function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_destination/6) it decodes the encoded string and will redirect to the correct path.

Try putting a few different URLs in [this online tool](http://jlpoutre.home.xs4all.nl/BoT/Javascript/Utils/endecode.html) and you'll see what they are *supposed* to look like when they're encoded properly.

Comment: Even i used $basepath.'node/'.$nodeid.'/delete?'.drupal_get_destination().

Comment: It still showing node/35414/delete?destination=node%2F821%3Fnid%3D35414

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? How are you 'placing' the destination in the URL, through code? And either way, what problem is the fact that the URL is properly encoded causing you and why?

Comment: As i mentioned in my question when i visit specific content type node deletion page, delete and cancel link appears. After clicking on delete button it redirect me on other location using rule module. But i don't want to redirect on same location when someone clicks on cancel link. I'm directly visiting this url http://localhost/root-folder/node/821/delete?destination=node/821?nid=35414 by typing. After clicking on cancel link i want to be redirected on this page http://localhost/root-folder/node/821?nid=35414 @clive

Comment: What happens if you try this...`$path = url("node/$nodeid/delete", array('query' => drupal_get_destination()));`?